# How to get the process priority in python

Tags: python, process

i want to get priority of a process with the PID in python 3.2 ?

for example i have the process with the PID of 3105

i want to do something like this

```
priority = getpriority(3015)
```

i am on Linux Debian 3.2

Comment: What OS are you targeting

Answer (score 0):

You could read `/proc/[pid]/stat` and look at the following field:

```
          (19) nice  %ld
                    The nice value (see setpriority(2)), a value in the
                    range 19 (low priority) to -20 (high priority).
```

See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Comment: how do i get the /proc/[pid]/stat in a human readable format?

Comment: Perhaps you want https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil ?  Or subprocess.Popen to /usr/bin/ps?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`psutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) module (portable, Windows/Linux are supported)

On windows, I have a `notepad` process under pid 27544. Iterate on the process list to find the process object.

```
>>> import psutil
>>> pid = 27544
>>> p = next((proc for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.pid == pid),None)
```

then call `p.nice()` without arguments to get the current nice value (system-dependent)

```
>>> p.nice()
32
```

32 is the "normal" value (Windows `psutil.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS`). Now I'm using process manager to change the priority to "lower than normal" and I run `nice` again:

```
>>> p.nice()
16384   # psutil.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
>>>
```